# Use postman or fiddler to check wcf service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, fiddler, postman

http://example.com/ShaktiERPService/UpdateErpSrvc.svc?wsdl

i have one wcf service URL similar to above url... where i written one method (**UpdateData**) with 4 parameters. And this method is returning a string as response like "**successfully updated**" or "**failed to update**"

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUpdateErpSrvc
{       
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "UpdateData/{Erp_Ord_No}/{SFDC_Order_No}/{usr}/{pass}")]
    string UpdateData(string Erp_Ord_No, string SFDC_Order_No, string usr, string pass);
}
```

and My method is here:

```
public class UpdateErpSrvc : IUpdateErpSrvc
{
    public string UpdateData(string Erp_Ord_No, string SFDC_Order_No, string usr, string pass)
    {
        ServiceRepository repo = new ServiceRepository();
        return repo.UpdateData(Erp_Ord_No, SFDC_Order_No, usr, pass);
    }
}
```

This service is working perfect in project...
But i want to check this in postman & fiddler....

I don't have any idea to check..

I tried so many time but didn't get response...

So please help me related to this problem..

Comment: use `SoapUI` for this.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps you,

1. Fiddler is **debugging** tool.
2. Postman is best suitable to **test your Web API methods**. It can also be
   used against **3rd party APIs** and Open .

So, if your web service is with **RESTful** properties you can go with Postman to test the functionality of your web service.

However you can have fiddler in parallel to check the Request and Response in various formats such as
Normal Headers

[image]

without any extra effort.
Also, **POSTMAN** helps you to easily add the header fields , data, etc with **Sophisticated User Interface** when compared to **Fiddler**

Update 1:

As per your sample Code you are trying to using a GET request which works absolutely fine, how ever not a recommended standard.

Also, would like to know if your using Entity Framework for accessing the data, if so update your post with the necessary code to help you further.

Comment: Sorry Aravind but i need more clarification.......... I am trying in postman but it's not working

Comment: No any response i am getting 400 bad request

Comment: how you are sending the data can you show the screenshot of postman request.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SOAPUI to test for WCF services. Check https://www.soapui.org/
to download. You can easily put your wsdl address and can just run your request.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use WCFTestClient for checking your WCF service. It would clearly show you the request and response in XML format.